# Email form missing_content message not showing

Tags: php, email

**solved**

I got this email form for a 404 page which is also suppose to display a message when something is wrong or the message has been sent.
The script was working fine, untill a recent update forced me to use `isset()` on a lot of lines to get rid of some errors.

Accept there is one message that I can't get to display; the missing_content message that is supose to display when both fields are left empty. The code:

```
    <?php
    $response = "";

    function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){
        global $response;
        if($type == "success") $response = "<p><div class='success' style='margin-right: 10vw;'>{$message}</div></p>";
        else $response = "<p><div class='error' style='margin-right: 10vw;'>{$message}</div></p>";
    }
    $not_human          = "Are you sure you're not a robot?";
    $missing_content    = "Please fill in every field.";
    $message_unsent     = "Something went wrong, please try again.";
    $message_sent       = "Thanks for your help, your message has been send.";
    $name       = wp_get_current_user();

    if (isset($_POST['message_text'])) {
        $message    = $_POST['message_text'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['message_human'])) {
        $human      = $_POST['message_human'];
    }
    $to = "fake@mail.com";
    $subject = "404 found by: " . $name->user_login;

    if (isset($human)) {
        if(!$human == 0){
            if($human != $_SESSION['outcome']) {
                my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human);
            } else {
                if(empty($message)){
                    my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
                } else {
                    $message = "link: http://vespa-ciao.nl" . $url . "\n\n" . $message;
                    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message));
                    if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent);
                    else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent);
                    // I was unable to test the message_unsent repons so I asume it works
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        // This is the message that is not displayed
    }
    $number = array( mt_rand(1,5), mt_rand(6,10) );
    $outcome = $number[1] - $number[0];
    $_SESSION['outcome'] = $outcome;
    ?>
```

It's the part almost at the bottom of the script that is not working for me. I've tried it without `isset()`, tried using a `$_SESSION`, placing it at the top, losing the `else` statement and I can't even remember all the other things I've tried but it just will not display.

Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you answered your own question you should create a proper answer below and accept it, not intermix the answer with your question above. That, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by changing:

```
if (isset($_POST['message_text'])) {
    $message    = $_POST['message_text'];
}
if (isset($_POST['message_human'])) {
    $human      = $_POST['message_human'];
}
```

Into this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['message_text'])) {
    $message    = $_POST['message_text'];
}
if (!empty($_POST['message_human'])) {
    $human      = $_POST['message_human'];
}
```

No more help required